# blank screen after wrapping App component with react-context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am writing the context API and everything is working fine but when I wrapped the App component with the context screen became blank

**Code of contex**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

const chatContext = createContext();

const ChatContext = ({ childern }) => {
  const [user, setuser] = useState();
  return (
    <chatContext.Provider value={{ user, setuser }}>
      {childern}
    </chatContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const ChatState = () => {
  return useContext(chatContext);
};

export default ChatContext;
```

**code of index.js before wrapping contex**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

****code after wrapping context api** **

```
import ChatContext from "./Context/ChatContext";

ReactDOM.render(
  <ChatContext>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </ChatContext>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**but the screen becomes blank anyone how can help me.**

I tried to solve this problem but can not able to do so. plz anyone how can help me will be appricated

Comment: what error do you see in browser console?

Comment: no error in the browser console

Comment: You misspelled the `children` prop as `childern` and so `childern` is `undefined` which is passed to the provider children property and nothing is rendered

Answer (score 6):

i think you just misspelled children  you wrote childern and if you fix how you wrote it the problem will be solved

```
const ChatContext = ({ *childern* children }) => {
  const [user, setuser] = useState();
  return (
    <chatContext.Provider value={{ user, setuser }}>
      {*childern* children}
    </chatContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const ChatState = () => {
  return useContext(chatContext);
};

export default ChatContext;
```

Answer (score -1):

their is spelling mistake in "childern" i should have write "children" thanks a lot its work for me thanks a lot